# Does Every Periodic Function Have An Associated Differential Equation?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

My question is the opposite to proving the existence of periodic solutions to ODE's.

Assume that $\ f(z)$ is a periodic function over the $\mathbb{R}$ , or doubly periodic over some lattice $\Lambda$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Where yes, $\ f(z)$ is smooth and continuous.

Can it be said that $\ f(z)$ is or must be a solution to some Ordinary Differential Equation? Or is periodicity not a strong enough attribute alone to assure the existence of an ODE?

Comment: With no assumptions on how smooth $f$ is? There are discontinuous periodic functions, such as $f(x)=\lfloor x \rfloor$.

Comment: Yeah, i was trying to post the question ASAP, i should have noted and have now edited that f(z) is smooth. In the case of functions with poles, i would figure with techniques from analysis the poles could be removed.

Comment: What kind of ODE?  Do you mean a linear ODE with constant coefficients?

Comment: Sorry i should have been less succinct. An ODE having constant or non constant coefficients. Really I wanted a general theorem that i might have missed in my research, but im getting the feeling there isn't one

Comment: maybe a weaker condition than general periodicity, would be periodicity + some re-occurrence relation is the coefficients of it power series

Comment: A smooth function need not be analytic, meaning it may not be representable as a power series. I'm also not sure why you think periodicity has something special to do with being a solution of an ODE: many ODEs have non-periodic solutions.

Comment: Of course periodicity isn't a condition that is required. For context I m dealing with functions known to be periodic but im unsure if they have a differential equation associated with them, what order it would be etc. A theorem that such an equation always exists would be of great help. As for the series, that is how I'm am defining the functions i am working with which is why i brought it up. =^.^=

Comment: What the ODE associated to $e^{\sin(z)}$ would be? If you allow non-constant coefficients, then it is trivially the solution of $f(z)-e^{\sin(z)}=0$, but otherwise...

Comment: If you allow arbitrary coefficients, _any_ function $f$ is a solution to an ODE, namely the zeroth order ODE $y=f(x)$.

Comment: I'll up vote you for your comment. Even thought stating   a solution that F'(z) - g(z) = 0 , when g(z) = F'(z) is a trivial and relatively useless statement. It is an answer to what i supposed was a question i asked that apparently really didn't get my point across. Thx for your reply though i get your point.

Comment: Maybe when i get the question with the correct restrictions I'll try again, thx for your help